# replicate a shadow with pure css

Tags: css

I need to do a shadow effect like the above image. I prefer css, so I am trying this code but the (smooth) borders are not identical. Any best approach?

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5vtDy/2/)

```
<div class="box"></div>

.box {
    height: 1px;
    width: 13em;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color:#191919;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #191919;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #191919;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #191919;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @downvoter, what is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure this just isn't an image? Where are you finding this shadow effect/approach?

Comment: @GordonsBeard The image is a jpg. But I would prefer a css alternative

Comment: You could probably use a radial gradient.

Comment: Which part are you trying to replicate? The radial gradient, or the shadow on the top?

Comment: @minitech, the idea is just replicate the image with css as identical as possible.

Comment: [Here’s my best effort, then :P](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/5vtDy/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/SG9pd/

```
div {
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)), color-stop(60%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a6000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Made with: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 1):

using just css here is the link to your solution

for demo

```
visit http://jsfiddle.net/a92My/
```